# Tab Bar not showing Images properly

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uitabbar

I have an app which is using tab bar. I have added images to tab bar items but the problem is that the tab bar is not showing the images properly.

**This is how I am getting:**
[image]

**But the correct display of images would be like this:**

[image]

I have tried many things and I have seen many posts of SO also, but I am not able to get the solution. I am neither getting the border nor the gradient effect inside the images when the are blue. I have added image of size 30x30. please suggest some solution. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you run in ios6 it will dislpay as what you want, currently you are displaying in ios7. and if you are running in retina device use 60x60 image size.

Comment: And why am I not getting the effect.? Has it been stopped in iOS 7.?

Answer (score 0):

If you run in ios6 it will dislpay as what you want, currently you are displaying in ios7.

and if you are running in retina device use **60x60** image size.

In ios apple use flat style so they have removed gradient style.

Comment: and what should be the size of the tab bar.? I mean the red background behind the buttons.?

Comment: 49 pts. and tab bar icon 30x30.